# Handle error coused by double reading schema

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

Everything works if a xml document has no a reference to an XML Schema

```
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.companyname.com/blabla" 
             xmlns="http://www.companyname.com/blabla">
```

But if the xml has the reference to schema on local machine like this:

```
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.companyname.com/blabla 
                                 Schemas\myschema.xsd" 
             xmlns="http://www.companyname.com/blabla">
```

This results with error "The global element 'TopElementName' has already been declared.

```
XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
xrs.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
xrs.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;

//xsd is located (intalled) in this same location where myapp.exe is. 
string startLoc = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string xsd = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(startLoc), "myschema.xsd");

using (Stream schemaStr = new FileStream(xsd, FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSchema s = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStr, null);
    xrs.Schemas.Add(s);
}
xrs.Schemas.Compile();

using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, xrs))
{
    while (r.Read()){}
    r.Close();
}
```

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the following flag:

```
XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:  Invoke your schema processor with options that tell it to read the schema documents you specify at invocation time, and to *ignore* the xsi:schemaLocation hints in the input being validated.  (If your schema validator doesn't have such options, get a new schema validator.)

The bogus xsi:schemaLocation in your first example should be fixed, independently of the validation options.